# Split different clauses in the sql statement ( select , from , where , group by etc )

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a select statement in the form of string in a Variable. This sql select statement could be of any complexity.

I have to extract different clauses ( select , from , where , group by etc ) from it. As I need to addend some code based on my business need into these clause, and remake the entire sql

```
    SELECT Accounts_Dly.Country
               AS Country,
           Accounts_Dly.LE_Book
               AS LE_Book,
           TRIM (TO_CHAR (Trans_Count_Feed_Stg.TRAN_DATE, 'dd/mm/rrrr'))
               AS TRAN_DATE,
           Accounts_Dly.Currency
               AS Currency,
           Accounts_Dly.Account_No
               AS Account_No,
           Accounts_Dly.Account_Name
               AS Account_Name,
           Accounts_Dly.Vision_GL
               AS Vision_GL,
           Accounts_Dly.Vision_OUC
               AS Vision_OUC,
           TRIM (
               TO_CHAR (Trans_Count_Feed_Stg.TRAN_AMT,
                        '999,999,999,999,999,990.00'))
               AS TRAN_AMT,
           Trans_Count_Feed_Stg.PART_TRAN_TYPE
               AS PART_TRAN_TYPE,
           Trans_Count_Feed_Stg.TRAN_PARTICULAR
               AS TRAN_PARTICULAR,
           Trans_Count_Feed_Stg.TRAN_ID
               AS TRAN_ID,
           Trans_Count_Feed_Stg.ENTRY_USER_ID
               AS ENTRY_USER_ID,
           Trans_Count_Feed_Stg.PSTD_USER_ID
               AS PSTD_USER_ID
      FROM Trans_Count_Feed_Stg  Trans_Count_Feed_Stg
           LEFT JOIN Accounts_Dly_View Accounts_Dly
               ON     trans_count_feed_stg.Country = accounts_dly.Country
                  AND trans_count_feed_stg.LE_Book = accounts_dly.LE_Book
                  AND trans_count_feed_stg.Contract_id = accounts_dly.account_no
     WHERE     Accounts_Dly.Country = 'RW'
           AND Accounts_Dly.LE_Book = '01'
           AND Trans_Count_Feed_Stg.TRAN_DATE BETWEEN '01-APR-2019'
                                                  AND '30-APR-2019'
           AND Accounts_Dly.Account_No LIKE '20__0245007001'
Group by Accounts_dly.Country;
```

I want to split above sql statement like below using regex:

```
1.SELECT Accounts_Dly.Country
               AS Country,
           Accounts_Dly.LE_Book
               AS LE_Book,
           TRIM (TO_CHAR (Trans_Count_Feed_Stg.TRAN_DATE, 'dd/mm/rrrr'))
               AS TRAN_DATE,
           Accounts_Dly.Currency
               AS Currency,
           Accounts_Dly.Account_No
               AS Account_No,
           Accounts_Dly.Account_Name
               AS Account_Name,
           Accounts_Dly.Vision_GL
               AS Vision_GL,
           Accounts_Dly.Vision_OUC
               AS Vision_OUC,
           TRIM (
               TO_CHAR (Trans_Count_Feed_Stg.TRAN_AMT,
                        '999,999,999,999,999,990.00'))
               AS TRAN_AMT,
           Trans_Count_Feed_Stg.PART_TRAN_TYPE
               AS PART_TRAN_TYPE,
           Trans_Count_Feed_Stg.TRAN_PARTICULAR
               AS TRAN_PARTICULAR,
           Trans_Count_Feed_Stg.TRAN_ID
               AS TRAN_ID,
           Trans_Count_Feed_Stg.ENTRY_USER_ID
               AS ENTRY_USER_ID,
           Trans_Count_Feed_Stg.PSTD_USER_ID
               AS PSTD_USER_ID

2.FROM Trans_Count_Feed_Stg  Trans_Count_Feed_Stg
           LEFT JOIN Accounts_Dly_View Accounts_Dly
               ON     trans_count_feed_stg.Country = accounts_dly.Country
                  AND trans_count_feed_stg.LE_Book = accounts_dly.LE_Book
                  AND trans_count_feed_stg.Contract_id = accounts_dly.account_no

3.WHERE     Accounts_Dly.Country = 'RW'
           AND Accounts_Dly.LE_Book = '01'
           AND Trans_Count_Feed_Stg.TRAN_DATE BETWEEN '01-APR-2019'
                                                  AND '30-APR-2019'
           AND Accounts_Dly.Account_No LIKE '20__0245007001'

4.Group by Accounts_dly.Country
```

Comment: What do you mean by *extract*? Do you want to replicate a parser that DBMS implements? Please clarify the requirement with actual applicable task and example

Comment: Please [edit] the question to show: **your** attempt to solve the problem; the issues/errors with **your** solution; and the expected output.

Comment: You may try to parse this SQL code: https://dbfiddle.uk/I48filUf

Comment: i have added example in the question

Comment: Your question implies the query is currently stored as a string; so how about storing a separate string for each clause, then add extra code to each clause as needed and concatenate them all together before executing? Trying to split an unknown query into multiple parts will be difficult and error prone.